# STARTTLS command failed when trying to connect via telnet

Tags: smtp, telnet

So I tried to connect to the smtp server belongs to google, via telnet, and this are the querys and answers I sent and got:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP a207sm820276wmd.25 - gsmtp
ehlo g
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [85.64.191.238]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS


Connection to host lost.
```

Why gmail smtp server is quiting anytime after I put the command STARTTLS?

Comment: Did you copy-paste the input and output from a real session, or rewrite it into the question body? Please copy-paste actual input and output, as you might (by mistake) add errors if you rewrite the text (which you *have*).

Comment: As for your problem, maybe you're disconnected because you don't start the TLS handshaking?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes.. this is the real comunication... If I want people to help me, I dont have a reason to trick them :X

I started it by the protocol I tried to connect to, dont I? (587)